# Calling random function without duplicates

Tags: javascript, random

I am creating a random photo365 challenge list generator using javascript.  I have a list of 365 different function which come up with a different assignment name/page link (this probably isn't the best way to do it, but it works) 
It works as it's supposed to, it does call 365 functions and puts them in a list...

But what I'd like to do is prevent repeats.  (Please note, the code below doesn't have all the 365 functions listed)

I have searched on stack overflow, and I have come across a variety of methods of preventing repeats. But any time I try to add the new code it, I can't get it to work.

I'm really not that skilled in javascript, so any guidance you could provide would be extremely appreciated...

Noel

//Create a new To-Do

```
function randomFrom(array) {return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];}
 function randomCreate() {
    var func = randomFrom([createNew365ToDo, 
                           createNew365ToDoBulb, 
                           createNew365ToDo2, 
                           createNew365ToDoShallow, 
                           createNew365ToDoWide, 
                           createNew365ToDoLenses, 
                           createNew365ToDoMacro, 
                           createNew365ToDoAToZ]);
    (func)();
}

function createNew365ToDoList()
{
    deleteAll365Rows();
    for (var p = 0; p < 365; p++) { 
    { 
         randomCreate();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
//are arrays passed by reference? I don't remember, so let's just make it available to everything to demonstrate

var fnArray = [createNew365ToDo, createNew365ToDoBulb, createNew365ToDo2, createNew365ToDoShallow, createNew365ToDoWide, createNew365ToDoLenses, createNew365ToDoMacro,createNew365ToDoAToZ];

function randomFunction() {
    //get a random index from the list
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * fnArray.length);
    //save that function to fn, and REMOVE it from the list
    var fn = fnArray.splice(index, 1);
    //return that function - now, when randomFunction() gets called again, you won't ever 
    //return the same function since it's no longer in the list
    return fn;
}

function callRandomFunction() {
  var func = randomFunction();
  (func)();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I tried the code, but I get the following error in the developer console:
TypeError: func is not a function

Comment: edited, didn't notice I had the two functions called the same thing